# Review audit gone awry

Tags: support, review, review-audits

I just did a review for a late post.

It was of poor quality and I decided to edit the post. Upon clicking 'edit' I was redirected to a page saying "This answer has been deleted". After refreshing the review (seeing as I thought it would then disappear), the review was still there.

I retried editing, but got the same redirection. I went back to the review, and pressed "No action needed", with the thought that it had already been deleted and decided to relieve the queue of this particular review.

The perceptive reader already knows the follow up because of the title: It was an audit and I "Didn't pass". I was set out to improve the post, and upon realizing it was deleted set out to relieve the queue.

Does anyone know if this was a bug (not being able to edit), or if the choice to edit was wrong as an action anyway?

Comment: Whenever people go to the "real" version of the question and see it is deleted, they somehow think "oh, no action needed, it's already been deleted." They need to think "aha! it's an audit! I'm being shown something that has already been deleted!" then click Flag or Recommend Deletion or the like. An audit pretends it hasn't been deleted. If you click No Action Needed you are saying it doesn't need to be - and that's wrong for this post, right?

Comment: @KateGregory: Which is kind of a problem; ideally, diligent reviewers should be able to pass audits even if they don't know that there *are* audits. Besides, *normally*, trying to delete an already-deleted post just gives an annoying error message, so it's pretty reasonable behavior (unless one is particularly suspicious, and knows about audits) to try to avoid it. That said, I know there's no easy way to fix this particular issue, so we'll probably just have to live with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4339524), the only thing you should have been doing on it is flag it as "Not an answer" - it's a question posted as an answer, no amount of editing it would make it a correct answer.

The fact that the post had already been deleted should have alerted you to the fact that it was probably an audit, and made you look more closely.

This is not a bug, the audit "worked" - your initial reaction wasn't the right one (at least IMO), and now you've got more information about what you should have done, so you'll be able to contribute even better to site maintenance :-)

Don't attempt to edit questions posted as answers, or spam, or offensive posts. Flagging is the only thing to do in those cases. Editing such content is a waste of your time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason I posted the question was to be able to (as you put it so nicely) "contribute even better to site maintenance". Pretty new to reviewing, but I understand I should have flagged it. Thanks!